# Sending excel attachment from google sheet but only current tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code works perfect but sends the whole sheet, I am wanting to only send the current tab/sheet.  How do I make it where it only captures the current tab columns A-H instead of the entire thing google sheet with all tabs?

```html
function send_report_email(spreadsheetId) {
  var spreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId(); 
  var file          = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
  var url           = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+spreadsheetId+'/export?format=xlsx';
  var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

 var fileName = (spreadsheet.getName()) + '.xlsx';
 var blobs   = [response.getBlob().setName(fileName)];

 var receipient = "andrew@barrelrace.com"
 var subject = "xxxx"
 var emailbody = "first line \n\nsecond line \n\nCheers!,"

 MailApp.sendEmail(receipient, subject, emailbody, {attachments: blobs});
  }
```

Comment: Try getting the Sheet ID and appending that to your URL as a `gid` parameter - see [this Stack Overflow question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000699/google-spreadsheet-direct-download-link-for-only-one-sheet-as-excel) answers for more details.

Comment: Can you give me an example by using the code above?

Comment: I figured out where to put the gid... but now I'm curious if I can have it only download columns A through H of that specific tab?

Comment: I might try something like copying the columns you want to a new, temporary, Sheet, get that sheet's GID, export the Excel file, then delete the temp sheet

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to achieve your goal:

1. Create a temporary sheet
2. Copy the data from A-H to temp sheet
3. Delete the columns after column H *(This is optional since you only copy the data of column A-H to a temporary sheet and some application may still show the deleted columns)*
4. Get the gid of the temporary sheet
5. Fetch the sheet by adding `/export?format=xlsx&gid='+tempSheetId` to the url.
6. Get the the response blob and attach to an email.
7. Delete temporary sheet.

### **Example:**

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
function send_report_email() {
  var spreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheetRange = sheet.getDataRange();

  //check if tempsheet is existing and delete if true
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("tempSheet");
  if (tempSheet != null) {
    spreadsheet.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
  }

  //copy data from Sheet1 to temp sheet
  var temp = spreadsheet.insertSheet("tempSheet", spreadsheet.getSheets().length);
  sheetRange.copyTo(temp.getRange(1,1));
  //remove columns after column H.
  temp.deleteColumns(9, 18);
  
  var tempSheetId = temp.getSheetId();    
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId(); 

  var url           = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+spreadsheetId+'/export?format=xlsx&gid='+tempSheetId;
  var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  var fileName = (spreadsheet.getName()) + '.xlsx';
  var blobs   = [response.getBlob().setName(fileName)];

  var receipient = "email here"
  var subject = "xxxx"
  var emailbody = "first line \n\nsecond line \n\nCheers!,"

  MailApp.sendEmail(receipient, subject, emailbody, {attachments: blobs});
  //delete temporary sheet
  spreadsheet.deleteSheet(temp);
}
```

**Email attachment:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname,-sheetindex)
- [deleteSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet)
- [deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deletecolumnscolumnposition,-howmany)

Comment: Thank you!  Figured out it's easier to just create a different tab.  Question, what's the code to get the GID for that specific tab using the regular code I attached above?  So where the var URL will actually get the current sheet gid instead of me having to manually type it in.

Comment: To get the GID of a specific tab, you can use [getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetid). In your code you can add `var sheetId = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Insert Sheet Name Here").getSheetId()` or `var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()`